# Convert string to numpy array of strings

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have a string of data `data = "1,Hey,234,4456,789"` that I want to convert into a numpy array. Whenever I try the code `numpy.fromstring(data,dtype=str,sep=",")`, I get the error "ValueError: zero-valued itemsize". What is the correct way to use this function so that it works as intended? The output I am trying to get is `np.array(['1','Hey','234','4456','789'])`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turn the string into a list of strings (with `split`) and give that to `array`.

```
In [21]: np.array("1,Hey,234,4456,789".split(','))
Out[21]: 
array(['1', 'Hey', '234', '4456', '789'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.fromstring()` is useful for reading numbers, but for tokenizing strings you can do this:

```
numpy.core.defchararray.split(data, sep=",")
```

Comment: This produces a numpy array with a list inside of it.